# Swift Error: Extra argument in call

Tags: swift

Why am I getting this error when the arguments for the function are the same as what's being passed?

```
class ViewController: NSViewController {

   func foo(path: String, arguments: [String], showOutput: Bool) -> Void {
   }

    @IBAction func a1(_ sender: NSButton) {
        let path = "/sbin/ping"
        let arguments = ["-c", "5", "google.com"]
        self.foo(path, arguments, true){ // I'm getting extra argument in call for true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
func foo(_ path: String,_ arguments: [String],_ showOutput: Bool) -> Void {
    /// Prerform task here whic you want to perform while calling this
    /// function or task with those Paramaters
}

@IBAction func a1(_ sender: NSButton) {
    let path = "/sbin/ping"
    let arguments = ["-c", "5", "google.com"]

    /// It is just a normal Function that accepts parameteres and
    /// Preform requred Task
    self.foo(path, arguments, true)
}
```

Comment: That works, thanks. I've got to try to remember those weird `_`'s

Comment: Welcome, Happy to help

Comment: @pguardiario The "weird" `_` are not actually needed. They are optional.

Answer (score 0):

The line (with the mysterious extra `{` at the end):

```
self.foo(path, arguments, true){
```

needs to be:

```
self.foo(path: path, arguments: arguments, showOutput: true)
```

The use of `self.` is optional.